# How to use local error_page when remote error_page not found?

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to create a fallback for my error_page. Basically, the logic should be something like the following:

1. load foobar.html
2. does not exist on remote server -> load 404.html from remote server to show 404 page
3. does not exist on remote server -> load 404.html on local filesystem

Loading both `localhost/404.html` and `localhost/global404.html` works, but when I break `localhost/404.html` (by removing the file from the http server) it does not show the `global404.html` page as I'd expect.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        error_page 404 /404.html;
    }

    location /404.html {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/404.html;
        error_page 404 /global404.html;
    }

    location /global404.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

The above works fine when I hit `http://localhost/404.html` (when the 404.html file is on the remote server it shows that, when I delete the file it loads the global404.html file).

However, when I type a non-existent page I just get the default nginx 404 page.

Comment: I don't have an authoritative answer, but it seems to me that `error_page` does not cascade. So while Nginx is processing an `error_page` it will not allow another `error_page` to trigger. As both of the errors are triggered remotely, I can't see any viable solution.

Comment: that was my assumption. I wonder if there's any other approach I can take with this. I thought `try_files` might be useful but it seems it'll only serve static files and there is no way to get it to proxy.

Comment: actually @RichardSmith - thanks to your comment i found the answer! Will reply and close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the wording of a comment left on the question, I managed to find the `recursive_error_pages` option which allows cascading/recursive `error_pages`. I feel stupid for missing it in the documentation.

But, simply doing

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    recursive_error_pages on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        error_page 404 /404.html;
    }

    location /404.html {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/404.html;
        error_page 404 /global404.html;
    }

    location /global404.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

worked a charm. I love nginx.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have not noticed that directive before.